# Apache HTTP client, request from specific network interface

Tags: java, apache, apache-httpclient-4.x

I have machine with 4 internet IP's and I want to know if I can make apache http client to make requests from specific ip/network interface

Comment: The 4 IP's belongs to the same subnet ?

Comment: Nope, different subnetworks

Answer (score 6):

Using HttpClient 4.3 APIs

```
    RequestConfig config = RequestConfig.custom()
            .setLocalAddress(InetAddress.getByAddress(new byte[] {127,0,0,1}))
            .build();
    HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet("/stuff");
    httpGet.setConfig(config);
    CloseableHttpClient httpClient = HttpClients.createDefault();
    try {
        CloseableHttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(httpGet);
        try {
            // do something useful
        } finally {
            response.close();
        }
    } finally {
        httpClient.close();
    }
```

Comment: Please explain more how this forces the request to go out a specific interface. Does the 127.0.0.1 localhost address have to be replaced with something specific to make it work? I have been given a similar requirement but don't know how to apply your solution. Thx.

Answer (score 0):

Never did this, but there is a [ClientConnectionOperator](http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/httpclient/apidocs/org/apache/http/conn/ClientConnectionOperator.html) interface (and some factories too) in the API to create the socket. Maybe you can implement your own and create the socket with a concrete interface.